# Exception: (Index -1 requested, with a size of 2) while retrieving data from a Cursor

Tags: android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-loader

Hey I have a problem with accessing the data from a Cursor in Android Studio.
I have two tables in the database **events** and **messages**. So each event in the events table may have multiple messages in the messages table. The event and its messages share a common **event_id**.
I am using **LoaderCallbacks** to get a Cursor from a **ContentProvider**. In the ContentProvider **query** method, I am using a rawQuery to **INNER JOIN** these two tables.

In this example I query for an event which shares its event_id with two messages from the message table. In the ContentProvider the rawQuery() method with the INNER JOIN was performed.
At this state I can see in the Debugger that the variable **mCount** from the Cursor is -1. I am not sure what this means but anyways, back in the **onLoadFinish()** method the Cursor now contains a variable **mCursor** and this variable again contains a variable **mCount** which is 2. Which makes sense, since the query should return a Cursor with two rows and since there are two messages. But now I try to get a String with the **getString()** method and the **CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2** is thrown.
I realy don't understand what this means. And I don't find any hint in die Cursor docs, what it means when mCount is -1.
Furthermore in the onLoadFinished method the variable mEditTable is null. And in other queries where I don't join anything it always contains a table.

I am quite sure that the issue somwhere lays with the INNER JOIN, since everything works fine if I use just a query method inside the ContentProvider.query method. But I don't know what I should do differently. I hope you might help me with this. I am aware that, if there is no message related to an event, this query will return an empty cursor with mCount = 0 and then  again an exception will be thrown. But this is not the case in this example.

EventProvider class:

```
public class EventProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final String LOG_TAG = EventProvider.class.getSimpleName();


private static final int EVENTS = 100;

private static final int EVENT_ID = 101;

private static final int EVENT_MESSAGE_ID = 102;

private static UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

private EventDbHelper mEventDbHelper;

static {
    sUriMatcher.addURI(EventContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, EventContract.PATH_EVENTS, EVENTS);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(EventContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, EventContract.PATH_EVENTS + "/#", EVENT_ID);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(EventContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, EventContract.PATH_EVENT_AND_ITS_MESSAGES + "/#", EVENT_MESSAGE_ID);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mEventDbHelper = new EventDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = mEventDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor retCursor;

    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case EVENTS:
            retCursor = database.query(EventEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case EVENT_ID:
            selection = EventEntry.COLUMN_EVENT_ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            retCursor = database.query(EventEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection,selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case EVENT_MESSAGE_ID:
            selection = MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MessageEntry.COLUMN_EVENT_ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};

            StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
            sqlQuery.append("SELECT ");
            if(projection != null && projection.length > 0) {
                for(String s: projection) {
                    sqlQuery.append(s).append(", ");
                }
            }
            sqlQuery.replace(sqlQuery.length()-2, sqlQuery.length(), " FROM ").append(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME);
            sqlQuery.append(" INNER JOIN ").append(EventEntry.TABLE_NAME).append(" ON ");
            sqlQuery.append(EventEntry.TABLE_NAME).append(".").append(EventEntry.COLUMN_EVENT_ID).append("=");
            sqlQuery.append(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME).append(".").append(MessageEntry.COLUMN_EVENT_ID);
            sqlQuery.append(" WHERE ").append(selection).append(" ORDER BY ").append(sortOrder).append(";");

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "SQL command for: " + uri.toString());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, sqlQuery.toString());

            retCursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery.toString(), selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI: " + uri);
    }

    retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return retCursor;
}
```

EventActivity:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {

    String[] projection = {
            MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MessageEntry.COLUMN_EVENT_ID,
            MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MessageEntry.COLUMN_SENDER,
            MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MessageEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
            MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MessageEntry.COLUMN_MESSAGE,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry._ID,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_DATE_ADDENDUM,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_STATUS,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_PICTURE_NAME,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_STREET,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_HOUSE_NUMBER,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_POST_CODE,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_CITY,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION,
            EventEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + EventEntry.COLUMN_SIGNED_UP
    };

    String sortOrder = MessageEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC";
    return new CursorLoader(this, mCurrentEventUri, projection, null, null, sortOrder);
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    int indexName = cursor.getColumnIndex(EventEntry.COLUMN_NAME);
    int indexImage = cursor.getColumnIndex(EventEntry.COLUMN_PICTURE_NAME);
    String imageName = cursor.getString(indexImage); //Here the Exception is thrown

    mEventName.setText(cursor.getString(indexName));


   mEventAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

If you need something else, I will upload it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2

**-1** with Cursors will generally be 1 of 2 issues :-

1. that the column name passed to `getColumnIndex` is not a name of a column in the output.
2. that the Cursor is at the beginning that is at the position that is  "before the first row", as is the case when a Cursor is returned.

I suspect that your issue is due to 2 as I believe the message indicates the row of the column.

**2** can happen if a move???? (e.g. moveToFirst, moveToNext) method was not actioned ***(I cannot see any such move in your code)*** or that the result was not checked (the move methods return true or false to indicate whether or not the move request could be satisfied).

- see (probably `moveToFirst`)

  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#move(int)
  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToFirst()
  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToLast()
  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToNext()
  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToPosition(int)
  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToPrevious()

The fix would be to move the Cursor to a row, checking if the move was actually successful and to then extract the data.

e.g.

```
String imageName = "No Image"
if (cursor.moveToFirst() && indexImage > -1) {    
    imageName = cursor.getString(indexImage); //Here the Exception is thrown
}
```

- The above, `&& indexImage > -1`, would also weed out the situation where the column name does not exist in the Cursor.

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right. It was the second issue. Because the position of the Cursor was -1 and I tried to access a value from the Cursor. I used the moveToFirst method to move to the first row and then tried to access the data and it worked perfectly.  Thank you very much!